# HTTP REST and performing various actions - Web-based Active Directory application

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http, ldap

I'm building a web front end for common Active Directory tasks like details, creation, modification, disabling. I have the standard ones already working:

- HTTPPost for CreateAdUser
- HTTPGet for GetAdUser
- HTTPPatch for UpdateAdUser

Now my question is how (or what HTTP verb) should I link up the other common tasks like Enable/Disable, Reset Password, Terminate (which would disable the user, remove all groups, update the description, and move to a Deletions OU). Any suggestions or examples would be great. My first thought would be having a POST with an "Options" object that would look like:

- Disable = false
- Enable = false
- Terminate = false
- ResetPassword = false

Then pass that object in the body of the POST request with a switch handling the actual options when triggered true. I'm thinking that would work, but would that be the *right* way? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You don't want to call the same controller to invoke different operations. Separate your logic and avoid creating bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple operations for same verbs on same controller, you can define routing by adding method name {action} in the url.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And call URL like:

```
/api/operation/GetAdUser/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, really these operations are just LDAP Modify Requests:

- Disable = false
- Enable = false
- Terminate = false
- ResetPassword = false

I found a page that shows some of the [CRUD mapping options](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Create%20Read%20Update%20Delete).